# Hiding a html span based on a condition using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hide, conditional-statements

Trying to hide a span containing text and a textbox depending upon a condition. This  sets the value of each drop down after setting value I want to check each one and if the value does not equal 10 then I want to hide the span. Any help would be great. This code seems to be hiding all the spans  rather than the ones that aren't 10

```
$('.existing')
    .each(function() {
        var DD1 = $(this).attr('current');
        $(this).val(DD1);
        console.log(DD1);
```

//above selects the value of the html dropdown and below should check that value and hide span if its not 10

```
        var parent = $(this).parent().prev();
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        if ($(this).val(DD1) !== "10") {
            var hide = tr.find(".hideifnot").hide();
        }
    });



<asp:ListView runat="server" id="ListView1" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#">Type</a>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <a href="#">Address</a>
                    </th>                                                                                    
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
    <td>
                   <select id="DD" current="" class="existing">
                     </select>
    </td>
            <td>
               <input type="text" id="Type" class="TypeText "  value="<%# Eval("Type")%>" />                     
              <span class="HideifNot"> Address: <input type="text" id="Addr" class="AddrText "  value="<%# Eval("Address")%>" />  </span>              
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="button" id="btn_update" class="Update" value="Update" />
               <input type="button" id="btn_delete" class="Delete" value="Delete" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Client side of Listview only thing it contains is binding a list to it:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {  
                People i = Data;
                ListView1.DataSource = i.Addresses;
                ListView1.DataBind();
            }          

    }
```

Comment: Your class is `.existing`. Change this to `existing` if you wish to match the selector `.existing`

Comment: Can you please show the actual generated HTML? The server-side/templating script that generates the HTML is irrelevant to your question. (I'm also pretty sure that a `.` is an invalid character to use in a class-name.)

Comment: hmm...?not sure what u want me to show

Comment: @ERead: The HTML that was generated from the `asp:ListView`.

Comment: Like in the code behind .ascx.cs their isn't any

Answer (score 0):

Your select is missing the closing `>`.

It should be:

`<select id="DD" current="" class="existing">`

Instead of:

`<select id="DD" current="" class="existing"`

**EDIT:**
In addition, you should change:

```
var hide = tr.find(".hideifnot").hide();
```

To:

```
var hide = tr.find(".HideifNot").hide();
```

Comment: So maybe you can post the client code of the `asp:ListView`? It's hard to imagine with this code what is the problem.

Comment: only thing on client side is a databind from a list. added to OP.

Comment: You wrote the server side, not the client side... I meant to the "rendered code" that the user gets for the list view. You can find it at "view source" of the page.